# Error initializing SparkContext. java.io.IOException: No space left on device

Tags: python, apache-spark, cluster-computing, pyspark

After executing the shell command to launch a pyspark session: `pyspark --master yarn-client --num-executors 16 --driver-memory 16g --executor-memory 6g`

I get the following error:

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.IOException: No space left on device  
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method) 
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:253) 
etc ...
```

It seems that the slaves are out of disk space. How to clear it up?

EDIT: what I get when running `df -h` on the virtual machine I want to launch the job on:

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg01-lv01   20G   18G  2.5G  88% /
devtmpfs                    16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       16G  5.7G   10G  36% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       16G  1.6G   15G  11% /run
tmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rootvg01-lv03   20G  933M   19G   5% /var
/dev/mapper/rootvg01-lv02  2.0G   33M  2.0G   2% /tmp
/dev/sda1                  997M   92M  905M  10% /boot
/dev/mapper/rootvg01-lv04  1.6T  892G  734G  55% /data
```

Comment: Could you run "df -h" on the machine you are launching the job?

Comment: @facha thanks for the interest in my question. Here is what I get:

Comment: @facha it was not fitting as a comment so I updated my question

Comment: I guess maybe you have logs of previous runs, and you need to clear the application logs from the hdfs?

Comment: @AvihooMamka. Thanks, but I really don't know what is causing that. What I know is that I need to free up that disk space. Any way to do that? By the way I'm not in an application setting here. I was just performing some operations in pyspark, got an error saying that I was out of disk space, closed the session, and now can't start any new session

Comment: Check first what is eating your space. Try run: `sudo du -h -x --max-depth=1 /` and then `cd` to the biggest folder and execute the command again but with replacing the `/` to `.` to indicate to check the current location.

Comment: @AvihooMamka I may have zombie objects that were not killed when I terminated the previous session, that are still stored in slaves disk and that prevent me from starting a new session

Comment: @AvihooMamka when I execute your first command I get `We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.`
 should I proceed?

Comment: LOL. That's probably because of the use of `sudo`. If you can proceed then do it. This command prints the size of all your 1st level directories in `/` aggregated with its sub-directories.

Comment: @AvihooMamka OK. I get `my_username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.` Sounds like I'm in trouble now LOL

Comment: Try do the command without the sudo and check your output.